# Equivalence between $\pmb{\text{sup metric}}$ and $\pmb{\text{euclidean metric}}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

What shown below is a reference from "Analysis on manifolds" by James R. Munkres

[image]

So don't know which is $\pmb{\text{sup metric}}$ so I ask to show it definition and so I ask to show that the $\pmb{\text{euclidean metric}}$ is equivalent to $\pmb{\text{sup metric}}$. So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Euclidean norm and $\sup$-norm are defined on p. 4: $\lVert x \rVert = \sqrt{\langle x,  x \rangle} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}$ and $\lvert x \rvert = \max(\lvert x_1 \rvert,\ldots,\lvert x_n \rvert)$. This induces the Euclidean metric $d(x,y) = \lVert x -y \rVert$ and the $\sup$-metric $d(x,y) = \lvert x -y \rvert$. Also on p.4 Munkres states that $\lvert x \rvert \le \lVert x \rVert \le \sqrt{n}\lvert x \rvert$. The proof is straightforward and implies that the metrics are equivalent:

$$\lvert x \rvert^2 = \max(\lvert x_1 \rvert^2,\ldots,\lvert x_n \rvert^2) = \max(x_1^2,\ldots,x_n^2) \le \sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 \le n \max(x_1^2,\ldots,x_n^2) = n \lvert x \rvert^2 .$$

Answer (score 1):

The Euclidean metric is given by $d(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i)^2}$ while the sup metric is given by $d'(\mathbf{x}. \mathbf{y})= \max_{1 \le 1 \le n} |x_i -y_i|$.

They are equivalent because for all vectors

$$d'(\mathbf{x}. \mathbf{y}) \le d(\mathbf{x}. \mathbf{y}) \le \sqrt{n}d'(\mathbf{x}. \mathbf{y})$$

so being "near" in one metric means being "near" in the other, so they define the same open and closed sets, bounded sets, convergent sequences etc etc. Even uniform convergence in one is equivalent to uniform convergence in the other.

Comment: Okay, however how to prove that $d'(x,y)\le d(x,y)\le\sqrt{n}d'(x,y)$?

Comment: Then clearly if $d(x,y)<\epsilon$ then $d'(x,y)<\epsilon$ and so $\mathcal{T}_d\subseteq\mathcal{T}_{d'}$; but if $d'(x,y)<\epsilon$ how to prove that $d(x,y)<\epsilon$?

Comment: The inequalities are quite clear, i would think. And if $d'(\mathbf{x}. \mathbf{y}) < \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{n}}$, $d(\mathbf{x}. \mathbf{y}) < \varepsilon$ which gives an inclusion of topologies too. @AntonioMariaDiMauro

Comment: Hi professor Brandsma, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655304/continuity-implies-uniform-continuity)?